# Change the background color when disabled is true

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-class

How to change the background color of an input field when disabled is true.How to use `ng-class` for disabled input field.

```
//html
<div>
<input type="file" ng-disabled="false" id="id1">
</div>

//Controller

document.getElementById("id1").disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have scope variable for ng-disabled and use it with ng-class

```
<input type="file" ng-disabled="shouldDisable" ng-class="{'disabledCssClassName' : shouldDisable}" id="id1">
```

Then in controller manage disabled state of your controler by setting shouldDisable = true/false and define css class in your stylesheet

Comment: This would work, but I think it's overly complicated. Couldn't you accomplish the same thing using a css selector instead of using angular? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled  edit: using a scope variable to determine if the input is disabled is the better way to do it. My comment is only talking about the styling part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ng-class while you can use ng-style:

```
 <input type="file" ng-disabled="false" id="id1" ng-style="{'background-color': disabled? 'red' : 'green'}"
```

Comment: but then you're mixing presentation style into your content/model, so if you want to re-skin your site/app next year you will have to crawl through _every_ file. Better to use external styles in `.css` files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the `ng-class`

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.disabled = true;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .ng-disabled {
    background: #E9B96E;
  }
</style>

<span ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
Disabled? <input type="checkbox" ng-model="disabled"/>
<br/>

<!-- sets `ng-disabled` as class when `disabled` var is true! -->
<input ng-class="{'ng-disabled': disabled}" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-value="disabled? 'Disabled': 'Enabled'"/>

</span>
```

And here you can see how to achieve the same goal using the CSS [:disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled) selector (see below snippet). This requires less code and can be applied to all `input`s in an easier way.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.disabled = true;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<style>
  input:disabled {
    background: #E9B96E;
  }
</style>

<span ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
Disabled? <input type="checkbox" ng-model="disabled"/>
<br/>

<input ng-disabled="disabled" ng-value="disabled? 'Disabled': 'Enabled'"/>

</span>
```